# How to interpret the meaning of ${x%,*} and ${x#*,}

Tags: linux, bash, escaping

**Problem formulation:**

let's say I have a file called `pairs.tsv` where each line contains a comma separated pair of, for instance, paths to files:

```
% cat pairs.tsv  
path1,path2  
path3,path4
```

The following code iterates through each line and splits it where the `comma` occurs and then echos each result of the split.

```
for line in $(cat pairs.tsv); do  
echo ${line%,*}  
echo ${line#*,}
% returns:
path1
path2
path3
path4
```

I would like to know the meaning behind these `${x%,*}` and `${x#*,}`; especially `%,*` and `#*,` part. I know what they do, but I don't know **how** they do it! And what these special characters are called!

The reason that I am interested to understand how this is down, is to be able to replicate the same logic in other situations. Therefore, any kind of hint is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: A quick `man bash` would answer both questions

Comment: Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) also [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Comment: Quick remark: `for line in $(cat pairs.tsv); do` is horrible! [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `${x%,*}`

  - from the **end** of the string `$x`,  remove the **last** comma and any following characters
- `${x%%,*}`

  - from the **end** of the string `$x`,  remove the **first** comma and any following characters
- `${x#*,}`

  - from the **beginning** of the string `$x`,  remove characters up to and including the **first** comma
- `${x##*,}`

  - from the **beginning** of the string `$x`,  remove characters up to and including the **last** comma

I use these tricks to remember the differences:

- on my US keyboard, `#` comes before `%`
- `##` is greedier than `#`